# Qt- using getline function

Tags: c++, qt, getline

I am using Qt 5.2.1 and here is part of a function that I want to use in my program -

```
while( getline(in,str,':')
{
getline(str,'\n');
int var = atoi(str.c_str());
}
```

my question is how can I implement this in qt?

I searched the docs a bit and found out about readline and split but I dont know how to use them

any help is much appreciated. :D

Edit - my first getline checks for ':' in the text file and the second one picks up the number (that comes after ':') and converts it into a integer and stores it in a variable.

2 edit :

Here's how my text file looks like...

500 - 1000  : 1

1000 - 1500 : 2

1500 - 2000 : 7

2000 - 2500 : 6

the 1, 2, 7, 6 are the values that I need in my program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do. If you're trying to read a file:

```
QFile file("/path/to/file.whatever");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text) {
   // error message here
   return;
end

while (!file.atEnd()) {
    QString line = in.readLine();
    // now, line will be a string of the whole line, if you're trying to read a CSV or something, you can split the string
    QStringList list = line.split(",");
    // process the line here
}
```

`QFile` closes itself when it goes out of scope.

If you're trying to split a string based on the `:` delimiter you have there, use:

```
QStringList list = line.split(":");
```

**EDIT:**

Now that you defined what you want to do (read a like like this "value:integer"), you can easily do that with QStringList. Example:

```
QString input = "value:1";
QStringList tokens = input.split(":");
int second = tokens.at(1).toInt();
```

Of course, you'll need to use your own error checking, but this is an example of what I think you're trying to do.

Comment: What does the split function do exactly?

Comment: If you have a string like "what,does,it,do" and you split it based on ",", you'll get a string list (basically, an array) of "what", "does", "it", "do"

Comment: Thanx another question... how do convert the string to integer
(my text file has a number after ':' and I want to store that in a variable (int))

Comment: I have a little problem....  This function take the value from the text file and saves it in the variable but the problem is it takes the last value from the text file.

Comment: I want it to take value from every line and save those values to some variables......